# Yammer API requests return 401

Tags: python, json, yammer

I am trying to retrieve user like information using Yammer and requests. I am getting  401 status codes repeatedly.

Below is my code:

```
import json
import requests
import requests.auth


access_token = "mytoken"
headers = {"Authorization": "bearer " + access_token}
response = requests.post("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/liked_message/702068900.json", headers=headers)
me_json = response.json()

return me_json['name']
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: May be `response.text` will provide some informaion

Comment: Have you looked at their [python SDK](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/python-sdk).

Comment: The docs say `Bearer` with capital `B`. You should try that.

Comment: As stated by @klaus-d change the capitalization. You can also take your token and test it with curl, Fiddler, or other tool that will let you make this HTTP request.

Comment: Not an Answer but a correction for the future viewers of this code : import requests.auth is not needed as you are already importing the complete requests module.

Answer (score 1):

401 means you are not authorized, for more on status codes - https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Your credentials are either incorrect or you are simply not authorized.

> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If
>   the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401
>   response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
>   credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the
>   prior response, and the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the
>   entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include
>   relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is
>   explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access
>   Authentication"

Answer (score 0):

"The docs say Bearer with capital B" Right on the money mate. Thanks heaps as I
spent a few hours on this .

Comment: Hi Nick. Would you click the tick mark to the left of this question? That's how we indicate that a correct answer has been received. Ta!